# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer'

Tags: swift, metal

## What I'm trying to do

Initialise a buffer for metal that contains an `Int` value

## The Problem

```swift
import MetalKit

...

func doStuff(gra: [Int], dist: Int) {
    let graphBuff = device?.makeBuffer(bytes: gra,
                                      length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size * count,
                                      options: .storageModeShared)
    let distanceBuff = device?.makeBuffer(bytes: dist, // Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer'
                                      length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size,
                                      options: .storageModeShared)
}
```

for some reason it does not allow to init a buffer with type `Int`, but `[Int]` is fine.
I'm kind of at a loss here what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is Swift has some compiler magic for passing arrays to unsafe pointers. This magic doesn't extend to just regular types.

You can kinda do similar thing to the magic compiler is doing yourself using  this freestanding function from standard library `func withUnsafeBytes(of: &T, body: (UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> Result(UnsafeRawBufferPointer) throws -> Result) -> Result`

For example:

```
  3> var someInt: Int = 3
someInt: Int = 3
  4> withUnsafeBytes(of: &someInt) { print($0) }
UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: 0x00000001000ec4d0, count: 8)
```

But instead you can just make a regular buffer with

```
let buffer = device?.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Int>.size,
                   options: .storageModeShared)!
```

and then put anything you want in it using `contents()` pointer:

```
buffer.contents().storeBytes(of: dist, as: Int.self)
```

Comment: I hot fixed it with `var dist_arr: [Int] = [dist]` - so basically it want's an array to I gave it an array with only the `Int` in it. but your solution way better. Thanks!